# using nutch 1.4 in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, nutch

I try to use nutch 1.4 crawler in ubuntu however when I try to execute nutcg with all the setting that are suggested in nutch wiki it gives this error:

```
erogol@erogol-G50V:~/Desktop/search engine/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local$
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 1
bin/nutch: line 108: [: /home/erogol/Desktop/search: binary operator expected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: engine/apache-nutch-1/4-bin 
/runtime/local/logs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: engine.apache-nutch-    
1.4-bin.runtime.local.logs
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: engine/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/logs.      
Program will exit.
```

Do you have any suggestion or idea to solve the using problem for nutch?

Thanks in advance... all nutch knowers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't about nutch: the space within the `search engine` folder name creates problems. As you can see from the `ClassNotFoundException` the part after the space is taken as name of the class to be executed. Can't you just rename `search engine` to something else like `search-engine`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solced the problem. That was about the one of the config file ...

Comment: Downvoter, I'd like to know why! You should leave a comment at least!